# Bootstrap modal with Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have site navigation in Component A (Navigation).
I have a working bootstrap modal in component B (BootstrapModal).
Component A is referenced in index.html to display navigation.

What I'm trying to accomplished is a way to invoke modal window from Component B when a user clicks on a nav item containing “example” CSS class.

So will need conditional statement to invoke the modal when the CSS class is present.

Note that this is using bootstrap modal and am not able to add data-target="#myModal" to component A.

Comment: Vanilla Javascript and Bootstrap typically do not go along...

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Just use bootstrap's api on the click event of the item you want to target with an `if` statement based on the `hasClass` function in jQuery:

```
$('#myTarget').on('click', function(e) {
  if ('#myElement').hasClass('example') {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }
});
```

Note: I know you said "Vanilla javascript", but the fact that you are using Bootstrap seems to indicate that you are not using pure "Vanilla Javascript". Just that you need a programmatic way of opening the modal.

Comment: Thanks Matt, a slight change in approach to solving this but I got the idea from your solution.

Comment: Awesome to hear. Best of luck on your project.

Comment: Question was about pure JavaScript but answer contains Jquery

Comment: Even though the question asks about "vanilla javascript", that's not really valid. Bootstrap **requires** jquery. And I addressed that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a response to Matt's comment in his answer:

> Note: I know you said "Vanilla javascript", but the fact that you are
> using Bootstrap seems to indicate that you are not using pure "Vanilla
> Javascript". Just that you need a programmatic way of opening the
> modal.

I am posting it as an answer since I currently have less then 50 rep and can't post comments.

Also, this may not have been relevant back when Matt wrote his answer, but it is now, so here it is:

Bootstrap 5 is [dropping jQuery](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2020/06/16/bootstrap-5-alpha/) so any new code which uses or aims to use Bootstrap 5 will need a different answer than Matt's answer to this question. Again, this is not an answer, I didn't find one. Just want to raise the awareness. Currently, this makes upgrading to Bootstrap 5 a bit harder.

Answer (score -3):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('a.className').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          jQuery('#myModal').modal('show');
     });
});
```

Comment: The title said Vanilla JS, it means in pure JavaScript.